# Empty reports in Pentaho Client Console

Tags: jndi, pentaho, report-designer

I'm trying to publish a report to the bi-server, so I can visualize it from the Client Console (http://localhost:8080/pentaho/Home)

I configured successfully a JNDI data source to a remote Database (Oracle 10g) from the Administration Console, this is the url I used:
    jdbc:oracle:thin:@MY_SERVER_IP_HERE:1521:orcl

But when I visualize my report, I see no data at all, only static stuff: labels, pictures and so on.

Note that I have the bi-server started, also the administration console and the server where I have my database is working too, the proof is that I can see data from the report designer when I do a preview.

In the bi-server log, I found this right after I invoke the report: [CascadingDataFactory] deprecated behavior: None of the data-factories was able to handle the query 'Infos'. Returning empty tablemodel instead of failing hard.

Is it because I run a bi-server 4.1 with Report-Designer 3.9?

Does any one have any idea to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bi server version conflict with the PRD,
check this http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/PEOpen/Pentaho+Release+Product+Version+Matrix

Comment: Please note that link-only answers are not encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

How did you created that report? did you use report designer?. It sounds to me that there is an issue in the report it self and not in the BI server

**UPDATE**
To many messages, what does mondrian says when retrieving the data? I think you should verify your jndi by making an small bi xaction file that shows a couple of columns of your table in jPivot. Its not hard, you can create one easily using examples if you are not that familiar with the xaction.

Oh, i totally forgot this and you might be familiar already with that but, did you put the java driver for oracle inside the Administration Console driver directory?

Comment: Yes, I did it with Report Designer, The preview shows Data from the DataBase.

Comment: and you used the same jndi configuration in report designer and in the bi server? Have you seen the catalina log? Also, does the report receives input from the user or everything is hardcoded in the report?

Comment: First how can I see the catalina log? is it from the bi-server console when I run the script start-pentaho.bat?. But I'm sure that I used the same JNDI, because I configured it in the Administration Console and connect to it from the report designer via it's name.

Comment: No the report receives no input from the user, it's very basic

Comment: they should be at `$PENTAHO/tomcat/logs/catalina.out`. To know more about the logs [pentaho log](http://wiki.bizcubed.com.au/xwiki/bin/export/Pentaho%20Tutorial/Pentaho%20logs?format=pdf)

Comment: The only thing I see that could be helpful is the lines of log that I already post from the bi-server log.